# What objects should I use for this?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have to build something similar to this on iPhone:
[image]

But I don't know what elements to use (an `UITableView` maybe?). The elements will vary in size, depending on the amount of info I'll be getting. Note that this screenshot is made on Android and it's only an idea of what it should look like. Thanks!

Comment: And the screenshot is where exactly?

Comment: @Michal Forgot to put it, thanks! Just edited my post. Sorry about that :<

Comment: Use `UIScrollView` and stack it on top of each other - `UIImageView`, `UITextView`, `UIButton`...

Comment: It's not repetitive enough to make use of `UITableView`

Comment: @Michall Hmm, alright, I could do that. I have an XML from where I'm getting the info for each section (Description, Address etc.) so I was thinking about something that would have those sections, that's why a table view was my first thought. For reference, the XML looks something like this http://homebuyeralert.ca/listing-xml.php?list=91337

Comment: I would think you want the text area scrolling but for the rest of it (buttons, pic) to remain in place. You could possibly use a table with cells customized for each text item, however I agree the scroll view might be a better option. I personally fine the table view easier to work with but I think the scroll view should provide a cleaner implantation. Also, consider whether autolayout has a role in dealing with this given the need to support various screen sizes.